# Replacing multiple row patterns in CSV with Regex and PowerShell?

Tags: regex, excel, powershell, replace, filter

I have an Excel file that has multiple thousands of rows of data that I retrieve from a SharePoint server with various PowerShell scripts.

The rows' content is structured very similarily:

```
General/Categoryname /ADMIN_XXXX_YEAR(random stuff here)/more_random_stuff_here.filetype
```

The problem is I need to filter out everything except for the `ADMIN_XXXX_YEAR(randomstuffhere)` part.

In terms of regex I would be looking at something like:

http://www.regexper.com/#General\%2F%28\w%2B%29\%2F%28\w%2B%29_%28\d%2B%29_%28\d%2B%29\%28%28.*%29\%29

(although to be fair `(\w+)\/(\w+)_(\d+)_(\d+)\((.*)\)` should suffice by itself).

Yes, I know that my Regex-Fu isn't exactly top notch but the expression will generally serve the purpose I need since it will find what I need. The problem here is mostly that from what I've understood and searched on StackExchange there is no way to apply this to Excel without a VBA script. There is the internal search and find although I am unclear on how performing a search like this will function. Perhaps there is a way of doing this in PowerShell that I am unaware of?

If anyone has some informative material that could help me along I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want, but did you try [The Import-Csv Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx)?

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot easier if you were extracting as CSV instead of Excel format (the CSV will still open in Excel). Or is in CSV? Title doesn't quite match the description.

Comment: Its a CSV file that is generated using a powershell script, that retrieves all item names etc from a MOSS 2007 Server.

Unfortunately the regular methods of retrieving folder name do not work, i have pretty much tested the entire MSDN properties for the class that are available that would make sense.

The reasons for why this is done don't matter, I am aware of the Import-CSV function although i havent checked whether or not i can apply a regex filter in the way i require it yet.

Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done within Excel with a formula such as:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("ADMIN",A1),FIND("/",A1,FIND("ADMIN",A1))-FIND("ADMIN",A1))
```

assuming to be applied to Cell A1.

Or use Text To Columns with `/` as the delimiter and delete the surplus.

Comment: This is actually quite brilliant and might be the solution i was looking for. Although it kind of puts a cork in automating certain things this is definitely a step in the right direction. Let me do some fiddling and testing, i will report later/tommorow. From what i see so far though this is the answer i have been looking for :)

Comment: Done, working on the solution right now, will simply flag it tommorow :)

Thanks pnuts :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell out the `import-csv` suggestion, you could try something like

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$output = @()
$csv = import-csv yourCSVfile.csv
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  $string = select columnName
  $parts = $string -split "/"
  $output.add($parts[2])
}
$output
```

...assuming your string,

> General/Categoryname /ADMIN_XXXX_YEAR(random stuff
>   here)/more_random_stuff_here.filetype

is one column in the csv, and your portion consistently follows the 2nd slash. If your slashes delimit columns in the csv, you can just do `$output.add($string)` and skip the `$parts` stuff.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i have gone with the excel method for now, but i will be using this method in automation.

Thank you very much :)